# JavaScript removing copyright character from text

Tags: javascript, regex, text-processing

I am using some regex to remove white spaces from some text in JavaScript. The current regex looks like this:

```
var cleaned_plaintext = website_content;

cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.toLowerCase();
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/(\0\r\n|\n|\r|\0)/gm," ");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/\s+/g," ");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/[...\(\)]/g,"");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/[…]/g,"");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/[:!?.,={-}]/g," ");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/\s+/g," ");
```

The above regex does pretty good at cleaning up most white spaces but say I have symbols like these

```
©
```

How can I remove those with regex? Also any tips on cleaning up that above regex to make it more streamlined, faster, etc....

Comment: Perhaps state specifically what you want to remove

Comment: What do you think `/[...\(\)]/g` matches? Anyway, the two basic options you have are (1) list all the characters you want to remove, (2) list all of the characters you *don't* want to remove.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use \w, this way you can find "no word caracter", including white spaces you can to this:

```
'test  %%% © º§§§§§@@@@@  ;OK%'.replace(/[^\w]/g,'')
```

the result is:

```
"testOK"
```

Edit:

If you want to keep the white spaces, you can use this:

```
 'test  %%% © º§§§§§@@@@@  ;OK%'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]/g,' ')
```

result:

```
  "test                      OK "
```